# How do you fix "could not convert string to float" in Python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

To simplify, I have two columns in a dataframe, df, in Python Jupyter Notebook:

```
Column            Non-Null Count  Dtype  

Cash              57 non-null     object 
FX Rate           57 non-null     float64
```

I have tried to convert column 'Cash' to float as it may be a string. I then wish to create a new column that is simple multiplication of two columns, such as:

```
df["GBP Market Value"] = df["Cash"] * df["FX Rate"]
```

However I get the error:

*TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'*

df was created by pandas read_csv. If I open the data in Excel, I can do column multiplication so I'm thinking even if the underlying data in that 'Cash' column is a string, how can format the column to do the calculation in Python. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

df["Cash"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Cash"],errors='coerce')

Worked